# Why fetch request doesn't work in array map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, many-to-many

I have an array with objects (**person**), like this:

```
[ {id: 1, name: Tony},
  {id: 2, name: John} ...]
```

I add to database table **event** new row and get id value. After this, I need to add new rows to another table **personToEvent** with id value from **event** and id values from array **person**. Database table **personToEvent** should looks like this:

```
id | eventid | personid
 1 |     120 |        1
 2 |     120 |        2
```

But in fact, after adding new row to **event**, fetch isn't called. I don't know why

Here I add new row to **event**:

```
addEventToDatabase() {
    fetch(`${Config.baseUrl}/event/add`, {
      method: 'PUT',
      body: JSON.stringify(this.state.newEvent),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      }
    })
        .then((response) => {
          if (response.status >= 400) {
            throw new Error('Bad response from server');
          }
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(returnedData => {
          if (this.state.person.length !== 0) {
            this.addPersonToEvent(returnedData.id);
          }
        });
  }
```

Here I try to add new rows to **personToEvent**:

```
addPersonToEvent(lastEventId) {
    this.state.person.map(item => (
        fetch(`${Config.baseUrl}/person-event/add/${lastEventId}/${item.id}`, {
          method: 'PUT'
        })
            .then((response) => {
              if (response.status >= 400) {
                throw new Error('Bad response from server');
              }
              return response.json();
            })
        ));
  }
```

New rows aren't added to database table. There aren't errors in console. How can I add rows to **personToEvent** correctly?

---

In general, I try to realize many-to-many data model

Comment: can you see the requests being made in the browser developer tools network tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I click on button, which call **addEventToDatabase()**, I calling reload page at same time:

```
location.reload();
```

So, I commented this, and problem is disappeared